# What's wrong with this interface assignment?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm trying to build some old ActionScript code I just inherited, that I think was originally written for an older version of flex, and I'm just starting to learn the language. I'm getting an error on the following line that I don't know how to fix.

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.collections.Sort;
// ...
public var actualModelList : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
// ...
var actualSort : Sort = actualModelList.sort;
```

`1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type mx.collections:ISort to a possibly unrelated type mx.collections:Sort.`

I'mm assuming that `Sort` implements an interface, `ISort`, but in other languages I've worked with, this assignment seems legit. What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
var actualSort : Sort = actualModelList.sort as Sort;
```

Comment: It may have, but why don't you just make your variable be of type ISort? That way, you can be sure that custom implementations of the interface also work.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but I got the error `Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ISort.` I hadn't realized I needed to import the interface separately, which I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in your question itself, lets get with your words -

> Sort implements an interface, ISort, but in other languages I've worked with, this assignment seems legit. What's wrong with this code?

So as you know that Sort implements ISort interface or can say ISort is base for Sort class so Sort class can be cast into ISort but reverse is not true.